# Launch Terminal with Ctrl+Atl+T instead of new Nemo window

Tags: ubuntu, nemo

when I do Ctrl+Atl+T it launches a new Nemo wiwndows, instead of launching a terminal, whereas settings/keyboard/shortcuts/launchers indicates
"Launch a terminal"  --> Ctrl+Alt+T
Can you help me fix this?
Thanks
[image: b]